# DB2 and Excel Power Query connection failed

Tags: db2, maximo

I'm trying to connect to the IBM Maximo Asset Manager database which runs on DB2 but I'm getting an error where the host does not respond.

I have the hostname:port and DB name and I'm trying to connect using Microsoft driver. Using Excel 365 64-bit.

Could it be that my user credentials don't have the necessary permissions?

I've tried to connect with the user credentials I have (must be the minimum available honestly). I also have the host name, port and database name. I usually login via browser, but would like to connect directly for speed purposes.

Comment: Please edit your question to add facts, otherwise your question will get closed for lack of detail. Never write "getting an error" because it tells nothing. Instead write (in plain text, not pictures) in your question the exact error message (full text). Do not use comments to add facts because they are not searchable.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.